# How do I make the last column of my output include only each element of the list instead of the whole list?

Tags: python, list, datetime

I am using python to arrange data from some lists in columns. I am having issues as the last column includes all the elements of my list instead of each element per row.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

list = [5275116,5275140,5275164,5275188,5275212,5275236,5275260,5275284,
        5275308,5275332,5275356,5275380,5275404,5275428,5275452,5275476,
        5275500,5275524,5275548,5275572,5275596,5275620,5275644,5275668,
        5275692,5275716,5275740,5275764,5275788,5275812,5275836,5275860,
        5275884,5275908,5275932,5275956]

timestamp = [i * 300 for i in list]

for ts in timestamp:
    for element in list:
        print("{} - Auction Nr. - {}".format(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts), list))
```

My output ends up looking like this (just a part of it):

```
2020-02-27 08:00:00 - Auction Nr. - [5275116, 5275140, 5275164, 5275188, 5275212, 5275236, 5275260, 5275284, 5275308, 5275332, 5275356, 5275380, 5275404, 5275428, 5275452, 5275476, 5275500, 5275524, 5275548, 5275572, 5275596, 5275620, 5275644, 5275668, 5275692, 5275716, 5275740, 5275764, 5275788, 5275812, 5275836, 5275860, 5275884, 5275908, 5275932, 5275956]
2020-02-27 08:00:00 - Auction Nr. - [5275116, 5275140, 5275164, 5275188, 5275212, 5275236, 5275260, 5275284, 5275308, 5275332, 5275356, 5275380, 5275404, 5275428, 5275452, 5275476, 5275500, 5275524, 5275548, 5275572, 5275596, 5275620, 5275644, 5275668, 5275692, 5275716, 5275740, 5275764, 5275788, 5275812, 5275836, 5275860, 5275884, 5275908, 5275932, 5275956]
```

I want each row to look like this:

```
2020-02-24 10:00:00 - Auction Nr. - 5275116
```

Thanks!

Bouns: How can I convert the time into UTC? It is currently UTC+1

Comment: Change this `print("{} - Auction Nr. - {}".format(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts), list))` to `print("{} - Auction Nr. - {}".format(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts), element))`.

Comment: change from `list` to `element` on the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This iterates over timestamp and list_ (I added the underscore so you don't shadow the built in keyword `list`) at the same time:

```
from datetime import datetime

list_ = [5275116,5275140,5275164,5275188,5275212,5275236,5275260,5275284,
        5275308,5275332,5275356,5275380,5275404,5275428,5275452,5275476,
        5275500,5275524,5275548,5275572,5275596,5275620,5275644,5275668,
        5275692,5275716,5275740,5275764,5275788,5275812,5275836,5275860,
        5275884,5275908,5275932,5275956]

timestamp = [i * 300 for i in list_]

for ts, el in zip(timestamp, list_):
    print("{} - Auction Nr. - {}".format(datetime.fromtimestamp(ts), el))
```